# CountVectorizer alternative with Counter objects

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, counter

I have a rather large DataFrame (few thousands rows) with two columns: an ID and a Counter object for the tags associated to the ID. The Counter counts how many times the item has been associated to that particular tag.

Each item may have different tags, and the total amount of tags is around the thousands too.

Example:

```
df = pd.DataFrame([[1, Counter({'a': 4, 'b': 2})],
                   [2, Counter({'b': 1, 'c': 3})],
                   [3, Counter({'a': 3, 'c': 5, 'd': 1})]],
                  columns=['ID', 'count'])
```

My goal is to obtain a matrix of the tag counts, similar to what I'd get when using CountVectorizer() on a text.

My limited knowledge led me to write this code:

```
# Create empty list
list = []

# iterate trough DataFrame
for item in df.itertuples():

    table = pd.DataFrame.from_dict(item.count, orient='index').reset_index()
    table.columns = ['tag', item.ID]
    list.append(table)

tag_table = pd.concat(list, sort=False)
```

But, it's not really working.

Well, it may work, but it's still processing since append and concat are notoriously slow.

How can I solve the problem more efficiently?

Thank you!

Comment: could you provide a [Minimal, reproductible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example)? Two or three rows of the Dateframe are sufficient, and it makes your question a lot easier to understand. Also, what is your main goal you want to achieve with this Dataframe?

Comment: @chefhose Thank you for the feedback, I added a minimal reproructible example.
My ultimate goal is to cluster similar tags in order to reduce their number.

Comment: Thousands of rows is ridiculously tiny. Try a simple python loop. I'm very curious how you got yourself into a situation of a column of Counters, probably you can do something much more efficient if you are using the source first.

Comment: @PascalVKooten The source is a DataFrame of id - tag couples, I used df.groupby('ID') and then a loop to build the current DataFrame.
I'm not very knowledgeable so I'm open to any other alternative

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could use a [DictVectorizer](https://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.feature_extraction.DictVectorizer.html):

```
import pandas as pd
from sklearn.feature_extraction import DictVectorizer

df = pd.DataFrame([[1, Counter({'a': 4, 'b': 2})],
                   [2, Counter({'b': 1, 'c': 3})],
                   [3, Counter({'a': 3, 'c': 5, 'd': 1})]],
                  columns=['ID', 'count'])

dv = DictVectorizer()

dv.fit_transform(df["count"]).toarray()
# array([[4., 2., 0., 0.],
#        [0., 1., 3., 0.],
#        [3., 0., 5., 1.]])
```

Comment: Thank you, this worked flawlessly. I believe the .toarray() part was there only to make it printable, is that correct?

Comment: @GarrettCode Yes indeed, it was there only to show you the result, but you don't want to work with that most likely as the sparse representation is cheaper for memory.